# 4-bit counter using T-flipflop in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to design a 4-bit counter with  T-flipflop, here's what i did:

**1**- From a D-flipflop to T-flipflop:

```
module T_FlipFlop( clk,T, Q);
   input wire clk;
   input wire T;
   output reg Q;
   wire D;

   initial
   begin
      Q<=1'b0;
   end

   assign  D= T ^ Q;

      always @(negedge clk)
       begin
        Q<=D;
       end
endmodule
```

with RTL shematic :

[image]

following this "D_ff to T_ff" conversion:
[image]

**2**- Then, i instantiated 4 T-flipflops in the top module and connected the output of each flipflop to the `clk` of the next one:

```
 module Counters_FreqDividers( sysclk,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4);
   input sysclk;
   output wire Q1;
   output wire Q2;
   output wire Q3;
   output wire Q4;

    T_FlipFlop       num_1(.clk(sysclk),.T(1'b1),.Q(Q1));
    T_FlipFlop       num_2(.clk(Q1),.T(1'b1),.Q(Q2));
    T_FlipFlop       num_3(.clk(Q2),.T(1'b1),.Q(Q3)); 
    T_FlipFlop       num_4(.clk(Q3),.T(1'b1),.Q(Q4));

 endmodule
```

with RTL schematic :

[image]

to follow this diagram:
[image]

We know that  T-flipflop is just a JK-flipflop with J and K connected to each other and that's what we have here, so consider them as T-flipflops.

**3**-The simulation:
[image]

**4**- Finally, my questions:

1) why `Q1` is the **ONLY** output that operates properly?

2) Why `Q2`, `Q3`, `Q4` starts with `1` although i have initialized them as `0`?

I can't figure out what's missing, i tried to play around but nothing worked and i'm stuck here!

**Edit**: my testbench:

```
 module test;

  // Inputs
 reg sysclk;

// Outputs
wire Q1;
wire Q2;
wire Q3;
wire Q4;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
Counters_FreqDividers uut (
    .sysclk(sysclk),
    .Q1(Q1), 
    .Q2(Q2), 
    .Q3(Q3), 
    .Q4(Q4)
    );

   initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    sysclk <= 1'b1;

      #200 $finish();
   end

    always #5 sysclk=~sysclk;

endmodule
```

Comment: yes it toggles  correctly, but in an opposite way; `Q2` is supposed to start with `0` then at the 1st falling edge of `Q1` toggles to `1`. However, in the simulation it toggles to `0` at the 1st falling edge of `Q1` . Consequently  'Q3' toggles  since it has witnessed a falling edge of 'Q2' and 'Q4'  also toggles for the falling edge of 'Q3', all happens at once.

Comment: yes! like you said,  and how can i solve this issue?

Comment: It worked after adding the `reset` signal! thanks a lot!

Comment: You can improve timing by using `sysclk` as the clock for all the T-Flip-Flops and have the `T` input be assigned the `Q` output of the previous flop.